# Divide dataset into 30

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm writing a model that I want to use to predict 30 days ahead. My problem is that I need to split the dataset into 30 chunks and when trying I get the error "array split does not result in an equal division".

Of course, this literally tells me the problem. So yes, I know the problem. My problem is that I can't figure out how to do an equal split. I've tried several different ways to calculate and split it and all end up with this error. I'm not certain where I'm doing wrong so I presume I haven't understood the problem. I'd like some help with this, wouldn't mind a good explanation so I understand it better too.

This is the split function:

```
# split a univariate dataset into train/test sets
def split_dataset(data):
  # split into standard weeks
  print(len(data)) # len is 2317
  train, test = data[1:-72], data[-72:-6] #328 for weekly
  # restructure into windows of weekly data
  print(train.shape)
  train = array(split(train, len(train)/30))#7 for weekly
  test = array(split(test, len(test)/30))
  #print(train.shape)
  return train, test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you have is probably that len(train)/30 is not an integer.

Let's take an example, if you have the following array a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], its length is 5. You cannot make it into 2 chunks as len(a)/2 is not an integer.

If you want to do it despite that, you have to remove parts of the array, or add neutral value. This is a design decision that you must make and that the split function of numpy cannot do for you.

So let's suppose you accept to lose the last data, meaning that the array [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] will be transformed into [[1, 2], [3, 4]], and the 5 is lost.

you can do this using the following snippet :

```
max_chunks = 30
max_nb_value = len(train)//30 # euclidean division : a = bq+r with r < q, this means that q (max_nb_value here) is the maximum number of element that we can take
array([train[i:i+max_nb_value] for i in range(0, max_chunks*max_nb_value, max_nb_value)])
```

Comment: Many thanks! This explains very well why it didn't work and present an acceptable solution.